# Quasar programatically closes popup dialog after all processing completes

Tags: asynchronous, modal-dialog, quasar, qdialog

I have a `q-dialog` component that has 2 buttons - `CANCEL` and `OK`. Cancel button uses `v-close-popup` but `OK` can't use that as it is doing some async data fetching, fill some UI element on the dialog and do some processing before it closes automatically. I tried to use `v-close-popup` and it results in undefined UI element when `document.getElementById` is called on the existing UI element because the dialog has closed before the processing completes. I need the UI element in the processing part because I use `easyqrcodejs` which needs a UI element to generate QR code. Any idea and insight is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without your code is difficult to know exactly what you need.

TEMPLATE

```html
<q-dialog v-model="isDialogOpen" />
```

SCRIPT

```js
setup() {
 async function fetchData() {
   // do some await things here

   // done with await update v-model (if using Composition API)
   isDialogOpen.value = false;
 }
 

  // ...
  return { isDialogOpen }
}
```

If you update your question with some code, I will update mine.